# Why does setting XMLHttpRequest.withCredentials = true allows CORS request?

Tags: cors, xmlhttprequest

The backend server returns

```
Allow-Control-Allow-Origin : *
Allow-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

So the server configuration is fine.

But when I make a request, if I don't set `withCredentials`  to be `true`, the server returns 401.

Now I want to understand why setting `withCredentials` works. Description on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) doesn't help much. How does allowing cookies make it work?

Imagine, the user has never opened the destination backend server site, so there must be no cookies for that site. Then what difference does using cookies in the request make?

Comment: In your case you must have either already opened the destination server site, or your request code is explicitly adding credentials to the request — for example, using the Authorization request header. But if your request isn’t explicitly adding an Authorization header to the request, then either try clearing the cookies for the destination server site in your browser, or try testing in a different browser that you’ve never before used to visit the destination server site. In those cases, no cookie will have been set already, so you should get a 401.

Comment: … or there is a redirect which tries to set cookies and then another redirect which checks to see if they exist. You need to provide an [mcve] with a clear problem statement (copies of all the request and response data from the network tab of the browser's developer tools for example). We can only speculate with what you've given us so far.

Answer (score 0):

`withCredentials: true` tells the browser to send cookies with the request.
if it's `false` the browser won't send the cookies which is most likely used by the server for authentication. 
When there are no cookies, the server can't authenticate the user and returns `401 Unauthorized`